# Does the value of disabled matter in HTML?

Tags: html

Is HTML:

```
<button type="submit" disabled>Some text</button>
```

equivalent to

```
<button type="submit" disabled="true">Some text</button>
```

And, would something like this work as well?

```
<button type="submit" disabled="You know it">Some text</button>
```

If it wouldn't work on a specific browser, can you say which one?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: @9Deuce Because I'm not anywhere near a computer that can program and won't be for about a day, but I'm curious *now*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only value `disabled` is allowed to have is `disabled`. You can omit everything except the value (`disabled`) in HTML 4 and earlier. You can omit everything except the name (also `disabled`) in HTML 5.

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes):

> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a
>   boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the
>   absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
>   or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's
>   canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes.
>   To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted
>   altogether.

This is fine:

```
disabled
```

This is fine:

```
disabled="disabled"
```

This is fine:

```
disabled=disabled
```

This is not HTML:

```
disabled="true"
```

This is not HTML:

```
disabled="You know it"
```

You can expect most browsers to perform error recovery on invalid values, but that is no reason not to simply write real HTML in the first place.